Can't download or update anything
I'm pretty sure this has something to do with corruption as my drive was corrupted just a few days ago but I managed to fix it.
The error occurs when I try to download or update anything, for example if i try to run sudo apt upgrade I get this.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'linux-generic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: files list file for package 'libxapian30:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

By the way im on pop os 22.04, jammy.

The files list for this package is broken anyway, you can delete it, which brings the package back into warning: files list file for package … is missing state, which is just a warning.
The files list is in /var/lib/dpkg/info/libxapian30:amd64.list, just delete that file.
Then, reinstall all packages that dpkg complains about, using apt reinstall linux-generic libxapian30.
In your case, I'd use apt reinstall ~i though -- reinstall all installed packages, that will rewrite all files and refresh all package information.
